# Why does Ubuntu fail to build amd64 architecture 4.20.1, 4.20.2, 5.0-rc2 kernel?

Tags: kernel

They have been failing to build the kernel for a while, what happens to them?

Comment: Could you provide more information, maybe a source link?

Comment: @PabloBianchi https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0001-base-packaging.patch is different in the two builds, and NVIDIA DKMS driver is the problem.

In patch row 299608
+do_dkms_nvidia=true

simple as that, I hope they will fix it.

edit: I can build 5.0 rc2 with "do_dkms_nvidia=false"

Comment: Everything is OK now. Missing packages are uploaded, and package rules are correct. Just kernels are not signed, be aware.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed this as well.  It's certainly odd.  You can see that the amd64 builds keep failing.  I've provided the links to the build logs, perhaps we can derive some insight from these.

- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.1/
- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.1/BUILD.LOG.amd64
- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.2/
- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.2/BUILD.LOG.amd64

Although for some reason v4.20 succeeded.  Weird?!

- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20/
- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20/BUILD.LOG.amd64

I bet one of the patches that they apply on top of the vanilla sources is causing problems...

I typically use UKUU to keep my system up-to-date with the latest mainline builds, so this is a little disappointing.

Hopefully they get this resolved soon!

Edit: It looks like the build is broken because of the nvidia driver.  It appears to be trying to build that kernel modules as part of the overall build process.  See the relevant lines near the end of the build log:

```
2019-01-10 03:38:12 (105 MB/s) - 'nvidia-kernel-source-390_390.87-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb' saved [8433608/8433608]

II: dkms-build downloading nvidia-390 (nvidia-dkms-390_390.87-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb)
--2019-01-10 03:38:13--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/nvidia-dkms-390_390.87-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.26, 91.189.91.23, 2001:67c:1562::16, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27288 (27K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: 'nvidia-dkms-390_390.87-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb'

     0K .......... .......... ......                          100% 9.46M=0.003s

2019-01-10 03:38:13 (9.46 MB/s) - 'nvidia-dkms-390_390.87-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb' saved [27288/27288]

linux:BuiltUsing=nvidia-kernel-source-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu4), 
II: dkms-build building nvidia-390

Creating symlink /home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/build/build-generic/______________________________________________dkms/build/nvidia/390.87/source ->
                 /home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/build/build-generic/______________________________________________dkms/source/nvidia-390.87

DKMS: add completed.
applying patch buildfix_kernel_4.18.patch...patching file conftest.sh
patching file nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-connector.c
patching file nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-encoder.c
patching file nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-helper.h
patching file nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm.Kbuild


Building module:
cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
unset ARCH; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.20.1-042001-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/build/build-generic/______________________________________________dkms/headers/linux-headers-4.20.1-042001-generic LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.20.1-042001-generic (x86_64)
Consult /home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/build/build-generic/______________________________________________dkms/build/nvidia/390.87/build/make.log for more information.
debian/scripts/dkms-build: line 121: /home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/build/build-generic/______________________________________________dkms/build/nvidia/390.87/4.20.1-042001-generic/*/log/make.log: No such file or directory
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:201: install-generic] Error 1
```

Edit 2: Opened a bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1811721